# Accordion with Icons to the Left

Tags: html, css, icons, accordion

I'm looking for an accordion with Icons to the left of the text instead of the right.

Currently using one off W3 Schools but I can't get the icons on the left side.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand the question, but maybe the solution lies in the study of Bootstrap, there you can connect different elements and get Accordion with Icons to the Left

For example, connect this:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/